# 1) Show that $(\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]^*, .)$ is infinite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

1) Show that $(\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]^*, .)$ is infinite.

2) Classify $(\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]^*, .)$, where $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]^*$ is the group of units of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]$

What I have done so far that for $a+b\sqrt2$ its inverse will be $\frac {a-b\sqrt2}{a^2-2b^2}$

Now $\frac {a}{a^2-2b^2} \in \Bbb Z$ &  $\frac {b}{a^2-2b^2} \in \Bbb Z$

What conclusion can be drawn from it about the cardinality of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]^*$?

One can post the answer also for the 1st part only.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^*$

Comment: How?? Please explain

Comment: $\{a+b\sqrt{2} \ | \  b=0\}$ Or does * mean units?

Comment: Be careful it is multiplicative group & $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]^*$ is the group of units of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}-1)=1$, hence $\sqrt{2}+1$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Then you have that

$$(\sqrt{2}+1)^2, (\sqrt{2}+1)^3, (\sqrt{2}+1)^4, (\sqrt{2}+1)^5, \dots, (\sqrt{2}+1)^k, \dots$$
are all distinct units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Finally, one can characterize units of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ saying that
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^* = \{ a+b\sqrt{2}: a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, a^2-2b^2=\pm1\}$$

EDIT: A proof of this fact follows:

Clearly "$\supseteq$" holds, for what you wrote in your question.
Viceversa, to prove "$\subseteq$", let $a+b\sqrt{2}$ be a unit. We want to show that $a^2-2b^2=\pm1$.

Let $c+d\sqrt{2}$ be its inverse.Then
$$ 1= (a+b \sqrt{2})(c+d \sqrt{2}) = (ac+2bd) + (ad+bc)\sqrt{2}$$
hence $ac+2bd = 1$ and $ad+bc=0$.

Now
$$(a^2-2b^2)(c^2-2d^2)=(a+b \sqrt{2})(c+d \sqrt{2})(a-b \sqrt{2})(c-d \sqrt{2}) =$$

$$ =1\cdot (a-b \sqrt{2})(c-d \sqrt{2}) = (ac+2bd) - (ad+bc)\sqrt{2} = 1+ 0 \sqrt{2} =1$$

hence $a^2-2b^2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. it is $\pm1$

Comment: How $(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}+1)=1$??

Comment: One of them should have a $-$. His answer is fine

Comment: How $(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}+1)=1$?

Comment: As I said, he has a typo $(\sqrt{2}-1)(\sqrt{2}+1)=1$

Comment: Yeah ok I get it sorry

Comment: Thanks for the help @Crostul

Comment: Sorry, I edited.

Comment: @Crostul can you please add the explanation why these $\pm 1$ case will only occur here for Q 2)?

Comment: Actually, the unit group is $\langle 1+\sqrt{2} \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You are right, but I think it's a deep result following by Dirichlet's Unit Theorem...

Comment: I think the unit group is ${\mathbb Z} \times C_2$, since $-1$ is a unit with order $2$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot $\pm 1$. But of course this can be proven without any deep Theorem. It is just a computation.